# Android : EditText and TextView are misaligned in alertdialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

In this code, I am making an `AlertDialog` with attributes title, `EditText`, `TextView`, Cancel `Button`, and Email me `Button`.

`EditText` and `TextView` not aligned/set properly.

```
// Alert Dialog
private void showForgotpasswdDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Forgot your password?");
    // Set linear layout
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    // View to set an dialog
    final EditText Email = new EditText(this);
    Email.setHint("Email");
    Email.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);
    // Text view
    linearLayout.addView(Email);
    builder.setView(linearLayout);
    // Text view
    final TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Unfortunately, if you have never given us your email, we will not be able to reset your password");
    linearLayout.addView(tv);
    builder.setView(linearLayout);
    // Buttons for EMAIL ME
    builder.setPositiveButton("EMAIL ME", new 
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            // Input email
            String email = Email.getText().toString().trim();
            beginforgotpasswd(email);
        }
    });

    // Buttons for CANCEL
    builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
             // Dismiss dialog
             dialog.dismiss();
         }
    });

     // Show dialog
     builder.create().show();
}
```

Please see the following screenshot showing the misaligned `EditText`:

[image: Here is an output of my actual code]

Comment: Your post isn't readable. Please change it

Comment: @GGK please check again

Comment: Hi BruTe. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve]). For this question, please describe the layout that you desire. Even better, attach a mock-up that shows us visually what you are trying to achieve. Thanks!

Comment: yes sir, I tried my best, sorry this is my third time to ask question @Elletlar thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just try it:

```
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

to get proper orientation!